# i / info icon: click it to reveal text / can this be done with css, and how?

Tags: javascript, html, css

See example:https://www.hatched.co.uk/let/pricing

Click the i icon and it expands to reveal text. I want to achieve the exact same thing. Can this be done with css? If so, how? If not, I am guessing JavaScript. If so, how?

Comment: Here is a css-only solution using "hidden" radio buttons to control on/off http://codepen.io/CesarGabriel/pen/tLDwH

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the "checkbox hack" where you bind a `label` tag to an input field via the `for` attribute, then use the contents of the label (your icon) to manipulate the checkbox, and use the `:checked` pseudo class and a sibling selector to toggle the display of some other element (your hidden text).

```css
.text,input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <input id="twitter" type="checkbox">
  <label for="twitter"><i class="fa-twitter fa"></i></label>
  <div class="text">twitter</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input id="facebook" type="checkbox">
  <label for="facebook"><i class="fa-facebook fa"></i></label>
  <div class="text">facebook</div>
</div>
```

Or using the same technique, you could use javascript to toggle a class on the link you clicked on and do the same thing.

```js
var icons = document.getElementsByTagName('i');
for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  icons[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

```css
.text,input {
  display: none;
}
.active + .text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <i class="fa-twitter fa"></i>
  <div class="text">twitter</div>
</div>
<div>
  <i class="fa-facebook fa"></i>
  <div class="text">facebook</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, no idea how I would add this to my site. Have a table similar to that on hatched and thus would want it to expand the same way on that sire. Also how do I replace the fa/tw icons with my own icon? Why does it link to that file you linked to?

Answer (score 1):

You can only toggle text on hover using CSS, not on click.

For that, I would highly advise that you use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).  You could then use the $.click function to set a handler, and use $.toggle to show/hide the text.

Jquery also has a built in sliding function [Jquery Sliding](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp)